# Kubernetes, see what pod has some specific IP address

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've noticed some logs in my Zabbix, telling me that some random IP, from my private subnet, is trying to log in as `guest` user. I know the IP is `10.190.0.1` but there are currently no pods with that IP. Does anyone have any idea how to see which pod had it?

The first thing I thought of, is looking and GCP Log Exporter, but we're not adding labels to logs with what POD it is. I'm sure I should be able to see it from the terminal level. So any suggestion would be nice.

Also, I know it won't be reserved but I took a look either way

```sh
gcloud compute addresses list | grep '10.190.0.1'
<empty line>
```

and

```sh
kubectl get all -o wide -A | grep 10.190.0.1
<empty line>
```

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 1):

Hi you are doing the right way.
I mean the:

```
kubectl get pods,svc -o wide
```

will effectively show you the pods and services and their IP. If the line is empty though, it is because there is no such IP in services or pods in your cluster workoads. two things to check:

- maybe the IP has changed
- maybe this logs come from an IP in the master node? something from the k8s control plane?

bgess